# how to toggle two image when I click one of them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, toggle

I have situation where in my page one text field and a small icon(edit.png) is there. Initially text field is in `readonly` mode & when I click this `edit.png` it remove the attribute `readonly` from text field. It works fine but now I want to do this:
 When click on `edit.png` it should remove the attribute `readonly` from text field as well as the icon itself change to `save.png` icon. This is my code. Please suggest where should I change to achieve this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function removeAlignment(x){
        var read=document.getElementById(x).removeAttribute("readonly",0);
        if(document.getElementById("toogle").value==="OK")
        {
           document.getElementById("toogle").value="SAVE";
        }
        }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
         a.table-actions-button {
            width: 1.25em;
            height: 1.25em;
            display: inline-block;
            background-position: center center;
         }
         .ic-table-edit { background-image: url("actions-edit.png"); }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <p>
     <label for="email">Email</label>
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="abcd@dsa.com" readonly="readonly"/>
     <a href="#" class="table-actions-button ic-table-edit" title="Edit" onclick="removeAlignment('email');"></a>
  </p>
     <input type="submit" id="toogle" value="OK" />
</body>
```

Where should I change? Please answer according to my Page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the edit.

```
if(document.getElementById("toogle").value==="OK")
{
    document.getElementById("toogle").value="SAVE";
    $('.ic-table-edit').css('background-image', 'url("actions-save.png")');
}
```

Comment: r u tested it? it's not working. I append it befor `function removeAlignment(x){` line. where should i write this???

Comment: still its not working. what you think?? i think it is for jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included j query plugin in your code.
With in the anchor tag,include `<img>` tag.
In toggle function,just change `src` attribute of your image to new image.
Find the example code below

```
<html>
<head>

    <script>
        function removeAlignment(x){
        var read=document.getElementById(x).removeAttribute("readonly",0);
        if(document.getElementById("toogle").value==="OK")
        {
           document.getElementById("toogle").value="SAVE";
           $("#image").attr("src","actions-save.png");
        }
        }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
         a.table-actions-button {
            width: 1.25em;
            height: 1.25em;
            display: inline-block;
            background-position: center center;
         }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <p>
     <label for="email">Email</label>
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="abcd@dsa.com" readonly="readonly"/>
     <a href="#" class="table-actions-button ic-table-edit"  title="Edit" onclick="removeAlignment('email');"><img src="actions-edit.png" id="image"></a>
  </p>
     <input type="submit" id="toogle" value="OK" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code is showing save button from beginning. I want to toggle this two.At first only edit button should show if i click on it, edit button will disappear & save button will show. r u sure its working like this??

Comment: Just change image names and keep desired names.I have changed image names according to your requirements.